# python: for-loop body before declaration and not indented?

Tags: python

I encountered this `python` code somewhere:

```
p = {
        s: path.join(
            dir , s)
        for s in samples
    }
```

Can somebody please explain or point me to documentation on two puzzling aspects of this code?

1. You can put the for-loop declaration statement (`for s in samples`) after the for-loop body in `python`?
2. The for-loop body has the same indentation a the for-loop declaration statement (`for s in samples`)? I thought that the body of a for-loop was required to be indented with respect to the for-loop declaration statement?

Comment: The for loop is placed after because it's a dictionary comprehension (similar to list comprehension). The one-liner, 100% equivalent is `{s: path.join(dir, s) for s in samples}`. The weird indentation is possible because of the brackets and the position at which a line can be skipped. I don't really know how to explain this part, someone may have a good explanation.

Comment: @Mathieu Inside virtually any bracketed expression, indentation doesn't really matter. Python uses indentation to know what part of the code belongs where logically; that is pretty unambiguous within brackets.